# Pass macro to be parsed by lua function in directlua

Tags: luatex

I have something like

```
\directlua{X = "width=0.5*\linewidth"} <-- invalid escape sequence

\directlua{X = "width=0.5*\\linewidth"} <-- Error

! Undefined control sequence.
\\->\let \reserved@e 
                     \relax \let \reserved@f \relax \@ifstar {\let \reserved...

l.254 ...X = "width=0.5*\\linewidth";}
```

X is used in a lua function like

```
function doX()
    --X = "width=0.5*\\linewidth"; --works fine
    tex.print("\includegraphics["..X.."]{...}");
end
```

So the problem isn't with the function or with what I am passing but the escape issue. Is this a catcode issue? Basically I want to pass LaTeX macros in strings to lua that eventually then get spit back out unmodified by the lua code but `\l` is interpreted as an escape sequence in Lua and `\\`, I guess, is weird by LaTeX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\directlua` primitive carries out full expansion of its argument before passing the resulting string to Lua. In general, it should only be used for small 'snippets' or for loading a separate dedicated Lua file

```
\directlua{dofile("name-of-file")}
```

as this avoids needing to worry about the TeX<-> Lua issues.

Where you are using `\directlua` with anything other than 'text' you have to keep an eye on the TeX expansion which will happen. With

```
\directlua{X = "width=0.5*\linewidth"}
```

as `\linewidth` is not an expandable token, the literal string is passed through to Lua. It then sees `\l`, which as the error says is not a valid escape sequence. With

```
\directlua{X = "width=0.5*\\linewidth"}
```

you have the TeX control sequence `\\`: this normally means end-of-line in LaTeX and has a definition which will expand but not 'properly'. You therefore get an odd error in the same way you would if you tried

```
\edef\foo{\\}
```

The correct approach *here* is to ensure that Lua sees the *value* of `\linewidth`:

```
\directlua{X = "width=0.5*\the\linewidth"}
```

If you want the calculation doing here, you'll need to allow for the fact that `\linewidth` is a dimension so perhaps

```
\directlua{X = "width=\the\dimexpr0.5\linewidth\relax"}
```

might be better.

If you want to arrange that Lua can return a TeX control sequence, you need to put a literal `\\` into the string: this is done using `\noexpand`. Thus if you aim to have `X` holding a string to return to TeX then

```
\directlua{X = "width=0.5*\noexpand\\linewidth"}
```

is the correct approach to take here.

---

For longer blocks one might consider using the `luacode` package. It defines an environment in which some catcode changes are made to make it 'easier' to put Lua code directly into a LaTeX document. There are a couple of things to watch out for

- Catcode changes and grouping make `luacode` non-expandable
- Like (almost) all LaTeX environments, `luacode` is a TeX group so any definitions at the TeX side need to be global to 'escape'

Using `luacode` one might have

```
\RequirePackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
X = "width=0.5*\\linewidth"
\end{luacode}
```

Comment: Thanks, the noexpand didn't work as I got some issue with missing dimension but `"width=\the\dimexpr0.5\linewidth\relax"` worked! Thanks!

Comment: @AbstractDissonance Without more context it's hard to be sure, but I suspect you got the error as you are using `width` in a context where TeX isn't expecting a dimen. (As I've shown, inside `\dimexpr` or similar would be fine, though without the `*`.)